# SELECT columns from a variable in Python PYODBC

Tags: python, sql, select, odbc

my first question up here, please be kind.
I am new to both python and SQL so I am finding my way. 
I am writing a function in python which should select columns from a table in the database with column names coming from a variable (list). Below is what I want the code to look like, obviously it does not work. Is there a way to do it, or I should not bother and instead of a list type column names directly into c.execute? Thank you! Alex

```
def data_extract1():
    column_list1 = ["column1","column2"]
    c.execute ('SELECT column_list1 FROM myBD' )
    for row in c.fetchall():
        print (row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `format()` and `join()` to replace `column_list1` in your query string with the columns you want.

```
c.execute('SELECT {} FROM myBD'.format(", ".join(column_list1)))
```

`", ".join(column_list1)` creates a comma-separated string from your column list.

`format()` replaces the `{}` in your query string with that new string

Comment: It works! Fantastic, thank you Mr. F!
What should I read to learn more about using this?